# Reading a text file and skipping lines that do not use the delimiter

Tags: java

So all I need to do is skip lines in a text file that do not use the delimeter, which is "\t".

```
private static final String delim = "\t";
```

some of the data is written as:

object \t price

while some are written as

object price (with just a space or two between them).

```
public void readFile(){

    int total=0;
    try{
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("prizeList.txt"));
        while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
            String nextLine = fileScanner.nextLine();
            String[] splitStrings = nextLine.split(delim);
            if(splitStrings.length != 2)
            continue;
            String name = splitStrings[0];
            double prize = Double.parseDouble(splitStrings[1]);
            prizes[total++] = new Prize(name,prize);

            if (total == 50) {
                break;
            }
        }

        fileScanner.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
}
```

Comment: `if(!line.contains("\t")) {
        // anything in here doesn't contain '\t'
    }`

Comment: Thank you, i believe that worked.